# Best way to programmatically copy, rename, and paste files in Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, file, batch-file

I have a directory C:\HotFolders where an application writes csv files every 15 minutes with the filename format YYYYMMDDhhmmss_DG@001991.csv.

I need to copy the new files (as they're created), and paste them into another directory with a minor change to the filename (_DG to _GWL).

I initially tried making an SSMS package
(described here: https://jimsalasek.com/2017/03/15/ssis-create-extract-file-with-date-and-time-for-a-filename/ )
to query a SQL database, generate the same file and export to the directory, but issues with SQL versioning has made running the SSIS package (.dtsx file) in SSMS unworkable for now.

I've tried a few python scripts to do this (below) but scanning the directory for the most recent file, copying, and pasting a renamed file on a schedule (say every 5 mins) is throwing me for a loop.

I know batch and powershell are options too, and even 3rd party software, which I'm open to.   I just need some guidance on the best approach to take and any code would be appreciated.

Python snippet

````
import os
files = [os.path.join('C:\\test', x) for x in os.listdir('C:\\test') if x.endswith(".csv")]
newest = max(files , key = os.path.getctime)```
````

Comment: This is not very clear.. Are you talking about getting the time and date from the file NAME or from its creation/last modified time? What do you consider to be _`the new files`_ ? Just pick the newest one and copy/rename that or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood well and this is what you're looking for:

```
Function Rename-Stuff{
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\HotFolders" | Foreach {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $_.Name.Replace("_DG","_GWL")} 
    Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\HotFolders")){ Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "C:\New\Path\Here"}
    Start-Sleep 360
    &Rename-Stuff}
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for, and if you'd like to understand what happening in this short script block; ill be more than happy to explain it (just dont want to assume you dont already know is all).

Oops, just realized you wanted to copy the items:

```
Function Copee-Stuff{
Copy-Item -Path "C:\HotFolders" -Recurse -Destination "C:\New\Path\Here" 
    Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\New\Path\Here")){ Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $file.Name.Replace("_DG","_GWL")}
    Start-Sleep 360
    &Copee-Stuff}
```

Please note: you can also filter by csv, and or any other file extensions provided the `-Filter` Parameter.

Comment: Nothing happens when I execute the ps1 script.  I'll need to play around and see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are you executing it? Paste it into an ISE pane, and type: `Copee-Stuff` in the cosole to run the function.

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

:again

:: Find latest converted
SET "latest=20000000000000"
FOR /f "delims=_" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "%destdir%\*_GWL*.csv" 2^>nul' ) DO (SET "latest=%%b"&GOTO gotlatest)
:gotlatest

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "%sourcedir%\*_DG*.csv" 2^>nul') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%q IN ("%%b") DO IF "%%q" gtr "%latest%" (
  rem for each later file
  SET "filenametail=%%r"
  ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%destdir%\%%q_GWL!filenametail:~2!" 
  COPY "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%destdir%\%%q_GWL!filenametail:~2!" >nul 
  ECHO Press X or Q to EXIT %~n0
 ) ELSE GOTO wait
)

:wait
:: wait 300 sec (5 min)
choice /c xqc /n /t 300 /d c >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO again

ECHO Process %~n0 EXIT...

GOTO :EOF
```

Commentary should suffice to decipher.